# Geometric probability with $[0,1]$ number line and $3$ points

Tags: probability

Q : On $[0,1]$ number line $3$ points : $A,B,C$ were chosen randomly.

What is the probability of $A\leq B\leq C$ ?

My attempt:

It will be cube with dimensions : 
$\Omega = [0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1] $

$F$ = Borel sets at $ \mathbb{R^{3}} $

Probability : geometric

I don't even know how to start. I've got some idea with triple integral to calculate this but I can't go through defining intervals for my integral. 
I will be very glad for any help, I'm struggling with this problem for couple of hours.

Comment: You have a uniform distribution for each univariate random variable. Integrate their joint density over $0\le a \le b \le c \le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following picture. Your set is an intersection of two half-planes: $a\leqslant b$ and $b\leqslant c$. The volume of this pyramid is simply $\frac{1}{6}$. Since the volume of a cube is $1$, our probability is also $\frac{1}{6}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well thinking about it as triple integral is easiest: 
You need to first set $C$, Then you set $B \in [0, C]$, and $A \in [0, B]$.
So we get integral:
$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^c\int\limits_0^bda\ db\ dc = \frac{1}{6}$$